# How to add new REST GET action to this Spring Boot code?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

This is a basic question coming from someone who just tried out Spring Boot 2 hours ago and a newbie to Java.

I followed the tutorial here;
http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/08/14/how-to-build-a-spring-boot-application-using-intellij-idea/

When I visit http://localhost:8080/api, I get the following json output;

```
{
type: "green",
length: 10,
height: 7
}
```

I would like to modify the code such that when I visit http://localhost:8080/api/test, I will get the following json output;

```
{
type: "red",
length: 8,
height: 7
}
```

The following is the controller code I modified;

```
@RequestMapping("/api/**")
@RestController
public class WidgetController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public Widget index() {
        return new Widget("green", 10, 7);
    }

    public Widget test() {
        return new Widget("red", 8, 7);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Apologies if this question looks too simple. It would  also be helpful if links are provided where I can learn enough to answer my own question. There seems to be so much to read for a newbie.

I am using IntelliJ idea Ultimate trial edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a @RequestMapping annotation for your test method with the desired path.  The one at the class level will map /api/* to this controller, but you have to give it more information about when to call test() versus index().  The way it is right now, any "GET" to an /api/* URL will get mapped to index().